# 4 dimensional array/ pointer in C++

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
double ****PsiDDiffj,
****PsiDDiffi,
****sDDiff,
r_h = 10;

int ****NorDiff,
numv = 100;
Generate_PsiDuopolyDiff() {
    int aa, bb, cc, dd;
    double vv_ja, vv_jb, vv_ia, vv_ib, deltav = r_h / numv, ll;
    PsiDDiffj = (double ****)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double***));
    PsiDDiffi = (double ****)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double***));
    sDDiff = (double ****)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double***));
    NorDiff = (int ****)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(int***));
    for (aa = 0; aa <= numv; aa++) {
        PsiDDiffj[aa] = (double ***)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double**));
        PsiDDiffi[aa] = (double ***)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double**));
        sDDiff[aa] = (double ***)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double**));
        NorDiff[aa] = (int ***)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(int**));
        for (bb = 0; bb <= numv; bb++) {
            PsiDDiffj[aa][bb] = (double **)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double*));
            PsiDDiffi[aa][bb] = (double **)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double*));
            sDDiff[aa][bb] = (double **)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double*));
            NorDiff[aa][bb] = (int **)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(int*));
            for (cc = 0; cc <= numv; cc++) {
                PsiDDiffj[aa][bb][cc] = (double *)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double )); //where the error happened
                PsiDDiffi[aa][bb][cc] = (double *)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double ));
                sDDiff[aa][bb][cc] = (double *)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(double ));
                NorDiff[aa][bb][cc] = (int *)malloc((numv + 2) * sizeof(int ));
            }
        }
    }
}
void
main() {
    Generate_PsiDuopolyDiff();
}
```

I want to create this 4_dimensional pointers, but visual studio told me **Access violation writing location** . I wan to know why it happened. Thanks! (why the systems asks me to add more details?)

Comment: Please don't do that if you're actually mean to write c++ code. Especially not if you're a beginner (as it seems to be obvious).

Comment: Yes. I am a beginner to C++. Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ and not C?

Comment: Oh, of course. I would suggest using the [c++ standard containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), or at least the usage of the [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) smart pointers. Don't manage dynamic storage allocation yourself, unless you're absolutely sure you need to do it.

Comment: Well, I have just learnt C++ for two weeks. And I have no knowledge on class. I only have learnt pointers yet.

Comment: Could someone tell me why access violation writing location?

Comment: you should change the tag, that is not typical C++ code.

Comment: @YuanchenLi You have more stars than the Hollywood Walk of Fame.

Comment: Give this a read: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer and think on what four stars can do to your reputation. Basically that much indirection opens you up to a whole world of hard-to-find potential problems.

Comment: in `aa <= numv` the `<=` usually results in off-by-one memory errors. It looks like you may be getting around these by overallocating (`numv + 2`), but it leaves a certain smell that other similar problems may be occurring

Comment: The code is attempting to allocate about 3 gigabytes. That will be a problem on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: and watch out for `void
main()` and the missing return type on `Generate_PsiDuopolyDiff`. Both are non-standard and a properly compliant compiler should be warning you.

Comment: Consider allocating one massive memory block and then splitting it up manually. What you currently have will exhibit very poor caching behaviour.

Comment: How closely are `PsiDDiffj`, `PsiDDiffi`, `sDDiff` and `NorDiff` accessed? A structure may make sense if the data is accessed as a row rather than four separate streams.

Answer (score 0):

I will bet real money that you're crashing because `malloc` is running out of memory at some point.  Assuming 8-byte `double`s and 4-byte `int`s, you're attempting to allocate `(4 * 8 + 4)*1024` bytes, or roughly 2.8 GiB for data alone, not to mention the overhead.

You should *always* check the result of `malloc` to make sure it actually succeeded before trying to use the allocated memory; if it can't allocate the requested memory, it will return `NULL`:

```
PsiDDiffj = malloc( (numv + 2) * sizeof *PsiDDiffj );
...
if ( PsiDDiffj )
{
  for ( aa = 0; aa <= numv; aa++ )
  {
    PsiDDiffj[aa] = malloc( (numv + 2) * sizeof *PsiDDiffj[aa] );
    if ( PsiDDiffj[aa] )
    {
      ...
```

C has not required you to cast the result of `malloc`<sup>1</sup> since the C89 standard, and under that standard doing so could mask a bug.  If nothing else, getting rid of it reduces visual clutter.

Similarly, given a pointer `T *p`, `sizeof *p` gives the same result as `sizeof (T)`; again, it's a little easier to read.  It also means that if you ever change the type of `p`, you don't have to chase down every `malloc` call and change the `sizeof` expression.

Given that the likely culprit is insufficient memory, you may want to look at a utility like `mmap` (or the Windows equivalent), which maps memory to disk.  Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with this sort of thing, so I don't have an example handy.

Barring that, you may need to re-think your approach.  Do you need all four matrices to be in memory at the same time?  Do you need all four dimensions of each matrix to be in memory at all times?  Can you work on single "page" of each matrix at a time (saving data to temporary files as you work)?

---

1. Note that this is *not* true in C++, but if you're using C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.